# Google form trigger options missing

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets, google-forms

I am implementing a Paid Time Off request workflow. Google provides all the code for this in [Request and approve time off Apps Script Enhancement](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d3IZxwjZqnUxijtFlA9Dk9t0WbZvva_NwEO8QIGAb88/edit).

I ran into a few issues and have fixed all of them except one; I cannot get the trigger I want. The instructions say to set up a trigger as follows:
Click "Resources>Current Projects Triggers"
Setup a new trigger. 
- The first field you should select "OnFormSubmit", select “From spreadsheet” for the second field, and the third field select "On Form Submit".
- Optionally click notifications and set-up an email address that will receive failure notifications. 
- Save

I select "OnFormSubmit" in the Run field as instructed but in the Event field, the only option I can select is Time-driven.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] and [mcve]. Rather than a coding problem this looks to be related to the development environment. As you are using the Google Apps Script editor, add details like the basic troubleshooting steps that you already followed (trying in incognito mode, try with a different web browser), starting from scratch rather than copying a file, the kind of Google account that you are using (Consumer account or Google Apps for Work account).

Answer (score 1):

I followed the tutorial example and was able to recreate the conditions described by it and not your problem.

The instructions in that tutorial say you should start from a copy of the spreadsheet example. Is this what you did or have you tried a blank Script project not bound to a spreadsheet?

If you have copied the code from the example into a Google Apps Script standalone script, the "From Spreadsheet" events will not be available to you. They are only available if you write you code in the script editor bound into a Spreadsheet.

[image: Screenshot following tutorial steps]

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. That was exactly the problem.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. That was exactly the problem but now I have an odd situation. I made the change and was able to set the trigger. I inadvertently selected the wrong function to run and submitted the form. I got an automated error message telling me of the undefined variable.  I fixed the trigger to run the correct function but now it does not get triggered on a form submit (based on the execution log). I added a second time-based trigger to call the same function and that reliably triggers and runs. Any suggestions on how to debug the "on form submit" trigger no longer running?

Comment: I've used various combination of emails, pushbullet and/or firebase to debug scripts. Essentially each Form submittal is a separate instance of the script so execution logs aren't always reliable live in instance you are debugging. Of those 3 options I've moved away from email except for deployed scripts. During development Firebase is realtime so more convenient.

Comment: I can tell the script is not running because the associated spreadsheet doesn't get updated. If I invoke the script from a time based trigger or via a Run command, the spreadsheet gets updated correctly. So the problem isn't with the script; it's with the script not being triggered by the "on form submit" trigger. I am not familiar with Firebase but would it help in a situation like this?

Comment: If the spreadsheet isn't being updated on form submittal do you mean now row is being added at all, or that your script isn't having an effect. At this point we can't help because you haven't posted any code to review. You can debug code line by line by adding sendMails or updating a field in a firebase db, the medium isn't important, tracking down where your code is failing is.

Comment: I decided to start again, and in following the steps you mentioned, it's now working correctly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. I'd appreciate you marking the answer as correct. Thanks.